# What is the most efficient way to get all the file names from a directory in Java?

Tags: java, performance

I've been playing around with various methods and seems that using a File[] seems to work the fastest (code below). I compiled and ran from terminal.

Test methodology was the average of 10 passes on each file path, with 4 file paths. file path 1 had 1470 files, file path 2 had 1435 files, and file path 3 and 4 both had 7 files each.

Results broken down by Method, then Sub-Method. First number is total time it takes to do both, second number is total memory used for the operations.

- File Array

  - For Each - 1,835,477 - 1,475
  - Iterator - 1,956,877 - 1,560
- J8 Stream Method #1

  - For Each - 5,420,527 - 1,409
  - Iterator - 3,241,518 - 1,466
- J8 Stream Method #2

  - For Each - 3,283,357 - 1,311
  - Iterator - 3,280,221 - 1,498

.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Testing {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int loopedTimes = 0 ; loopedTimes < 10 ; loopedTimes++) {
        for (int testCase = 0; testCase < 6; testCase++) {
            int argumentNumber = 0;
            for (String passedArguments: args) {
                int intM = 0;
                int postM = 0;
                LinkedHashMap<Integer, File> fileArrayTest = null;
                LinkedHashMap<Integer, Path> java8StreamForEachTest = null;
                LinkedHashMap<Integer, Path> java8StreamIterationTest = null;
                StringBuffer sb = null;
                int[] method = null;
                int[] test = null;
                String[] identifier = null;
                System.gc();

                intM = usage();

                fileArrayTest = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, File>();
                java8StreamForEachTest = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Path>();
                java8StreamIterationTest = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Path>();
                sb = new StringBuffer();
                method = new int[2];
                test = new int[2];
                identifier = new String[2];

                switch (testCase) {
                    case 0:
                        method = java8StreamForEachInput(passedArguments, java8StreamForEachTest);
                        test = forEachTest(testCase, argumentNumber, loopedTimes, java8StreamForEachTest);
                        identifier = new String[]{"For Each","For Each"};
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        method = java8StreamForEachInput(passedArguments, java8StreamForEachTest);
                        test = iteratorTest(testCase, argumentNumber, loopedTimes, java8StreamForEachTest);
                        identifier = new String[]{"For Each","Iterator"};
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        method = java8StreamIteratedInput(passedArguments, java8StreamIterationTest);
                        test = forEachTest(testCase, argumentNumber, loopedTimes, java8StreamIterationTest);
                        identifier = new String[]{"Iterator","For Each"};
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        method = java8StreamIteratedInput(passedArguments, java8StreamIterationTest);
                        test = iteratorTest(testCase, argumentNumber, loopedTimes, java8StreamIterationTest);
                        identifier = new String[]{"Iterator","Iterator"};
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        method = fileArrayInput(passedArguments, fileArrayTest);
                        test = forEachTest(testCase, argumentNumber, loopedTimes, fileArrayTest);
                        identifier = new String[]{"File Array","For Each"};
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        method = fileArrayInput(passedArguments, fileArrayTest);
                        test = iteratorTest(testCase, argumentNumber, loopedTimes, fileArrayTest);
                        identifier = new String[]{"File Array","Iterator"};
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                }

                postM = usage();
                // Spit out results
                sb
                    .append("loopedTimes | ")
                    .append(loopedTimes)
                    .append(" | argumentNumber | ")
                    .append(argumentNumber)
                    .append(" | testCase | ")
                    .append(testCase)
                    .append(" | ")
                    .append(identifier[0])
                    .append(" | ")
                    .append(passedArguments)
                    .append(" | Processing Time | ")
                    .append(method[1])
                    .append(" | ")
                    .append(identifier[1])
                    .append(" | Insertion | ")
                    .append(test[1])
                    .append(" | Elements | ")
                    .append(test[0])
                    .append(" | Total | ")
                    .append(test[1] + method[1])
                    .append(" | intM | ")
                    .append(intM)
                    .append(" | postM | ")
                    .append(postM)
                    .append("\n");

                try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("results/_" + loopedTimes + "-" + argumentNumber + "-" + testCase + ".txt", "UTF-8")) {
                    writer.print(sb.toString());            
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                argumentNumber++;
            }
        }
    }
}

static int[] fileArrayInput(String passedArguments, LinkedHashMap<Integer, File> fileArrayTest){
    long startFileArrayTime = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        File[] listOfFiles = new File(passedArguments).listFiles();
        for (File fileName: listOfFiles) {
            fileArrayTest.put(fileName.hashCode(), fileName);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long endFileArrayTime = System.nanoTime() - startFileArrayTime;
    return new int[]{ 0, (int)endFileArrayTime};
}

static int[] java8StreamForEachInput(String passedArguments, LinkedHashMap<Integer, Path> java8StreamForEachTest){
    long startJava8StreamForEachTime = System.nanoTime();
    try(Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(passedArguments))) {
        for (Path filePath : new Iterable<Path>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Path> iterator() {
                return paths.iterator();
            }
        }) {
            java8StreamForEachTest.put(filePath.hashCode(), filePath);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long endJava8StreamForEachTime = System.nanoTime() - startJava8StreamForEachTime;
    return new int[]{ 0, (int)endJava8StreamForEachTime};
}

static int[] java8StreamIteratedInput(String passedArguments, LinkedHashMap<Integer, Path> java8StreamIterationTest){
    long startJava8IterationTime = System.nanoTime();
    try(Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(passedArguments))) {
        paths.forEach(filePath -> {
            java8StreamIterationTest.put(filePath.hashCode(), filePath);
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long endJava8StreamIterationTime = System.nanoTime() - startJava8IterationTime;
    return new int[]{ 0, (int)endJava8StreamIterationTime};
}

static int[] forEachTest(int testCase, int argumentNumber, int loopedTimes, LinkedHashMap<Integer,?> passedLinkedHashMap) {
    int forEachElements = 0;
    long startForEachTime = System.nanoTime();
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("data/forEachElements1_arg-" + loopedTimes + "-" + argumentNumber + "-" + testCase + ".txt", "UTF-8")) {
        for (Entry<Integer, ?> entry : passedLinkedHashMap.entrySet()) {
            writer.println(entry.getValue().toString());
            forEachElements++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long endForEachTime = System.nanoTime() - startForEachTime;
    return new int[]{forEachElements, (int)endForEachTime};
}

static int[] iteratorTest(int testCase, int  argumentNumber, int loopedTimes, LinkedHashMap<Integer,?> passedLinkedHashMap) {
    System.gc();
    // Iteration - 1
    int iterationElements = 0;
    long startIterationTime = System.nanoTime();
    Collection<?> c1 = passedLinkedHashMap.values();
    Iterator<?> itr1 = c1.iterator();
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("data/iterationElements1_arg-" + loopedTimes + "-" + argumentNumber + "-" + testCase + ".txt", "UTF-8")) {
        while(itr1.hasNext()) {
            writer.println(itr1.next().toString());
            iterationElements++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long endIterationTime = System.nanoTime() - startIterationTime;
    return new int[]{iterationElements, (int)endIterationTime};
}

static int usage() {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long maxMemory = runtime.maxMemory();
    long allocatedMemory = runtime.totalMemory();
    long freeMemory = runtime.freeMemory();

    return (int)((freeMemory + (maxMemory - allocatedMemory))/1024);
}   
}
```

ps - sorry for the terrible formatting

 **EDIT** 
[5 Result Sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx7DO.png)

Comment: Dunno... maybe the one with the smallest test result numbers?  What's your definition of "efficient"?

Comment: How did you ensure the disk and system cache were clear before each run? What is the standard deviation?

Comment: I tried asking setting the values to `null` at the start of each iteration and then calling `System.gc()` to do it's job. I wasn't really sure how to properly clear the cache. @KevinO